# VersionInfo в Linux

Tags: linux, delphi, version

В Delphi есть диалог для добавления информации о версии в программу. Причем есть он и для платформы Linux

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как эту информацию достать? А точнее - как ее добавить в файл? Поиск по бинарному файлу строк из этого окна ни к чему не привел. В файле такие строки не найдены. В [документации](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Version_Info) о Линуксе ничего не сказано.

Я так понимаю, что какого-то единого стандарта для хранения версии в Линуксе нет?

Сейчас все, что я вижу - это формировать свой собственный ресурс со своим форматом и затягивать его в приложение. Но почему не работает стандартный механизм?

Comment: Вероятно потому, что в Linux нет стандартного механизма для указания версии в файле.

Comment: я бы ожидал, что из исходного кода версия будет доступна на этапе сборки через какой-нить макрос... а также что она будет указана в deb/rpm пакете при сборке оного...

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Тогда какой тогда смысл в наличии этого окна в IDE?

Comment: У меня вообще не даёт включить VersionInfo для Linux-проектов - выдаёт ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в проект файл с ресурсом.
{$R Version.RES}
Сам же файл компилируется из

Version.RC Который имеет вид примерно такой:

```
1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION 1,2,4,0
PRODUCTVERSION 1,2,4,0
FILEOS 0x4
FILETYPE 0x1
FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
{
BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
{
    BLOCK "040704E4"
    {
        VALUE "CompanyName", "My company\0"
        VALUE "FileDescription", "MY PROGRAM\0"
        VALUE "FileVersion", "1.2.3.4\0"
        VALUE "InternalName", "MY PROGRAM- V1234\0"
        VALUE "LegalCopyright", "© My company (2005)\0"
        VALUE "LegalTrademarks", "\0"
        VALUE "OriginalFilename", "\0"
        VALUE "ProductName", "Bla bla\0"
        VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.7\0"
        VALUE "Comments", "\0"
        VALUE "Author", "Vasya Pupkin\0"
        VALUE "Compiling Date", "20.05.2022 13:32:24\0"
    }
}
BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
{
    VALUE "Translation", 0x0407 0x04E4
}
}
```

Comment: Это просто, но вопрос был `Но почему не работает стандартный механизм?`